# removing untacked file and directories with git/info/exclude

Tags: git, gitignore

```
git version 1.7.11.7
Fedora 17
```

Hello,

I create a new git working resposity

```
git init
```

I added some files and some directories.

However, I have some files that I want to ignore based on my environment. I don't want to create a `.gitignore` file as I don't want it added to repository. Just my local.

So I want to ignore my `server/build` directory so I added it to my `.git/info/exclude` file.

```
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
 *.[oa]
 *~
 server/build
```

server is the root directory where I init my git resposity.

However, when I do git status I always get this directory in my untacked files.

```
# On branch dev
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
server/build/
```

I want to remove this from my git status.

I have tried the following with didn't work for me

```
git rm -r --cached server/build
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're leaving a blankspace before the pattern. Delete it and it should work:

```
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
*.[oa]
*~
server/build
```

If your repo doesn't have a `.gitignore` you could create one and ignore itself, too - but it really is more correct to use `exclude`, anyway.